# How can I loop through Excel worksheets, in multiple workbooks in the same directory while copying data into a new workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

This code by itself would loop through workbooks in a directory and copy data from specific cells on the first sheet to a new workbook. I would like to have it do that, but also go through each worksheet in each workbook to get the required data.

```
Sub GatherData()

    Dim wkbkorigin As Workbook
    Dim originsheet As Worksheet
    Dim destsheet As Worksheet
    Dim ResultRow As Long
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim RngDest As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set destsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set RngDest = destsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) _
                       .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    Fname = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/*.xlsm")

    'loop through each file in folder (excluding this one)
    Do While Fname <> "" And Fname <> ThisWorkbook.Name

            Set wkbkorigin = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Fname)
            'Set originsheet = wkbkorigin.Worksheets("1st")
            For Each ws In wkbkorigin
            With ws
                RngDest.Cells(1).Value = .Range("D3").Value
                RngDest.Cells(2).Value = .Range("E9").Value
                '.Cells(3).Value = originsheet.Range("D22").Value
                '.Cells(4).Value = originsheet.Range("E11").Value
                '.Cells(5).Value = originsheet.Range("F27").Value
            End With
            Next
            wkbkorigin.Close SaveChanges:=False   'close current file
            Set RngDest = RngDest.Offset(1, 0)
            Fname = Dir()     'get next file
    Loop
End Sub
```

This gives me the error:

> Runtime Error 1004, Application defined or Object defined error.

Previous versions of the code I have tried have done the following:

- Did not copy any data at all (using a "For each ws" statement)
- Error "Loop without Do" (using a for statement with counter)
- General compilations errors.

Comment: Helpful to indicate which line raises the error.

Comment: If there are other answers that indicate how to loop through each workbook in a directory, then all you have to do from there is nest another loop within that, to loop through all sheets in each workbook.

Comment: Also, unless I'm not understanding what you're trying to do, this looks mistaken: `.Cells(1).Value = ws.Range("D3").Value`. Though it won't cause an error, it is 99.9% likely to be equivalent to `ws.Cells(1).Value = ws.Range("D3").Value`, which is basically just overwriting a cell on the same sheet with the value from D3, etc.

Comment: I also thought it would be that simple, but the nesting just gives errors like "loop without Do" or The Application defined error I talked about earlier. This complier does not even highlight line that is causing the error.

Comment: And your right that line is wrong now that you mention. I'm not sure what I was thinking there

Comment: It is that simple, and a "loop without do" error indicates that you have a `Loop` statement somewhere without a corresponding `Do While` statement :D

Comment: Also, check again on your compile errors, it should highlight something, like: http://imgur.com/VrBpryH

Comment: Probably means you're attempting to *open* a loop with the `Loop` statement. You open it with `Do` or `Do While` or `Do Until` and close it with `Loop` or `Loop While` or `Loop Until`, and to make it even more confusing you can do basically the same thing with a `While/Wend` loop!

Comment: I edited the code above, funny enough I am unable to reproduce my "loop without do", but I this version does not copy any data all

Comment: You need to pay more attention to what you're doing... `rngDest` is defined as part of `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` Examine your variables, their parent/child objects. You're looping over every workbook in a directory, but for some reason at each iteration you are looping over only the worksheets in `ThisWorkbook`, see: **`For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`**.

Comment: Therefore, your `With RngDest` block is simply taking data from `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.Name)` because `ws` is defined as part of `ThisWorkbook` and dumping it into the `rngDest`. If there's no data in any of these sheets, then it will give the appearance that nothing is happening.

Comment: Have a look here, since it seems most of these can be identified if you're using basic [debugging](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) technique.

Comment: Thank you I will look through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct you need is:

```
Do While Fname <> "" And Fname <> ThisWorkbook.Name
    Set wkbkorigin = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Fname)
    For Each ws in wkbkorigin.Worksheets '### YOU NEED TO ITERATE OVER SHEETS IN THE WORKBOOK THAT YOU JUST OPENED ON THE PRECEDING LINE
        With ws
            ' Do something with the ws Worksheet, like take the values from D3 and E9 and put them in your RngDest range:
             RngDest.Cells(1,1).Value = .Range("D3").Value
             RngDest.Cells(1,2).Value = .Range("E9").Value
        End With
        Set RngDest = RngDest.Offset(1, 0) '## Offset this range for each sheet so that each sheet goes in a new row
    Next
    wkbkorigin.Close SaveChanges:=False   'close current file
    Fname = Dir()     'get next file
Loop
```

Also, and this is a tangent but I'll drop it here just to illustrate some possible point of confusion -- have a look at the several ways of iterating/looping in VBA:

```
Sub testing()
Dim i As Long
i = 0

'## do Loop can have a condition as part of the Loop
Do
    Call printVal(i)
Loop While i < 10

'## Or as part of the Do
Do While i < 20
    Call printVal(i)
Loop

'## You can use Do Until (or Do While) as above
Do Until i >= 30
    Call printVal(i)
Loop

'## Likewise, Loop Until (or Loop While)
Do
    Call printVal(i)
Loop Until i >= 40

'## You don't even need to include a CONDITION if you Exit Do from within the loop!
Do
    Call printVal(i)
    If i >= 50 Then Exit Do
Loop

'## Or you can use While/Wend
While i < 60
    Call printVal(i)
Wend

'## For/Next may also be appropriate:
For i = 60 To 70
    Call printVal(i)
Next


End Sub
Sub printVal(ByRef i As Long)
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print i
End Sub
```

Comment: So  I have stepped through the code like the guide you sent said, so I understand a little better what is going on. and like you said the code no goes through each ws and then attempts to place data where rng dest tells it to. I'm receiving a new error though "object does not support this property or method" My debugger honestly doesn't give me a line, maybe there is a setting for the debugger, im missing. I will update the code to reflect.

Comment: The debugger *always* highlights an offending line if you're getting that error. Step through code using F8 if in doubt, and take note of which is the last line you execute before the error occurs. It could be something as simple as a typo (i.e., `ThisWorkbook.Workshets` instead of `Worksheets`, etc. NB: If you've edited the code you're using, please update the code in the question accordingly, otherwise it's difficult to follow along with what you're doing :)

Comment: maybe I'm not doing it right, but I just paste over the code from my original question every time I make changes should I post the edited code in a comment instead

Comment: Oh also the offending line is "For each ws in wkbkorigin" if try to step into or step over that line I receive and error

Comment: Oh, sorry I did not see the updated code, but on second look yes you are doing it correctly. My mistake in the answer, it should be `For Each ws in wkbkorigin.Worksheets` :)

Comment: No you were right, you had it listed in your original post I must have over looked it. I'm getting no errors now, but also no results I will attempt to step through the code to figure out why

Comment: I added the `.Worksheets` after you mentioned the error to me, so it wasn't there originally.

Comment: The problem is your `RngDest` is not being redefined appropriately or at the right time.  Instead of `RngDest.Cells(1).Value = ...` do `RngDest.Cells(1,1).Value = ...` and so on. Then I think it will work.

Comment: yeah I fixed that, but there are no results being copied to the other workbook even by stepping through the code I can it is looping through each worksheet.

Comment: oh ok I will try that. Thank you for all your assistance and the guide was really helpful

Comment: You may also need to move the `RngDest` reassignment above a few lines, you need to redefined that range for each worksheet but you're not redefining it until you close each workbook. So the values keep getting overwritten. See revision.

Comment: It works! thank you very much I just need to work on excluding some worksheets from being copied and I'm in the money. I should be able to get that on my own. So how do I vote or close this question.

Comment: At the top/left of my answer, I think you'll be able to mark it as accepted in this space: http://imgur.com/Mn4QC1M